# Setting a htaccess with multiple URL conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I trying to create rules at .htaccess with multiple conditions without succeed.

I need all requests like:
`http://www.domain.com/portfolio-view/my-project-name/`

Redirects to:
`http://www.domain.com/#cbp=http://www.domain.com/portfolio-view/my-project-name/`

Only with URL that contains "portfolio-view" and not "#cbp=".

I'm trying to do that but it creates infinite loops.

Also, I'm trying that but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portfolio-view/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/#cbp=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually only have to check if the request starts with the string `/portfolio-view/`.

This should give the correct result:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portfolio-view/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/#cbp=http:\/\/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_‌​URI} [R=303,L,NE]
```

This one condition is `true` if the uri starts (`^`) with the literal `/portfolio-view/`.
`.*` means the condition should not care about what follows.

If the rule matches, you don't have to check for the other condition since it can not start with `/#cbp=` if it already starts with `/portfolio-view`.

I tested on a test machine and works just fine however I did it in my web-servers config file (under sites enabled directory, which I would recommend).

I tried it in an htaccess file and the example above worked just the same.

It seems like you can simply omit the `RewriteBase` directive If the .htaccess file is in the websites base directory. I tried your example on my test server and that's how my .htacces looks now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portfolio-view/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/#cbp=http:\/\/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_‌​URI} [R=303,L,NE]
```

On my test machine it redirects correctly.

For further reading I suggest:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
- https://regexone.com/

Comment: Thanks Takiro, I posted more info on the question above. I'm trying that but it doesn't work...

Comment: Okay, I'm not exactly sure but I think because of the rewrite base is set to `/` you have to remove the first / from the Condition. Changing `^/portfolio-view/.*` to `^portfolio-view/.*`

Comment: Changed answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work... When I go to `http://www.domain.com/portfolio-view/project-name/` doesn't do any redirect...

Comment: I now tried it with an .htaccess myself and you are right my example didn't work. I updated my answer with an example .htaccess file that worked on my machine and redirected correctly.

Comment: thanks Takiro, it still doesn't work, you can see that online in `http://www.generic.cat/portfolio-view/anna-vendrell-interiors/` when it should redirect to `http://www.generic.cat/#cbp=http://www.generic.cat/portfolio-view/anna-vendrell-interiors/`

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your requirement. try `RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/#cbp=http:\/\/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=303,L,NE]` instead. This should build the correct URL.

Comment: Thanks again. I have done the changes you told me but it doesn't do anything, you can check it on `http://www.generic.cat/portfolio-view/anna-vendrell-interiors/` The code actually is `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portfolio-view/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/#cbp=http:\/\/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_‌​URI} [R=303,L,NE] 
</IfModule>`

Comment: To be honest, I slowly run out of ideas. I've put the exact same thing in my htaccess file and it works flawlessly. The only thing I can think of is that you don't have permissions to rewrite urls or the .htaccess file is completely ignored by the webserver for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you could check if your .htacces file is even used by provoking an 500 error (writing nonsense in the files (which i don't recomend if the site is in production)) or put an `<directory / ></directory>` in that file and check the log if it mentions a "Directory not allowed here".

Comment: Also I just noticed you left out the `RewriteBase`, have you tried it with rewritebase set? As I mentioned in my answer it made no difference for me but maybe it works for you if it's set. If you have access to your websites config file I recommend to configure your rewrite there instead of an .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi Takiro. Finally it worked; I copied it just on the beginning of the .htaccess file, not in the end like I did before. Thanks for all!